# Change style through typescript or javascript in Ionic3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I want to add a specific type of style in ionic 3 Super tab view, where the app title bar translates to the top as much scroll to the top and if the user scroll down the header will be translated to the down like Whats App. I didn't understand how to get this awesome effect.

Edit:-

In Ionic3 when we use super tab,in the tab page have the ion-header and the remaining is

```
<super-tabs>
  <super-tab [root]="page1" title="First page"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="page2" title="Second page"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="page3" title="Third page"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

you can check more here [link](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs)
and others page only have ion-content. Now my desire is when user scroll on the other pages, the  tab page's header will be animate like whats app..when user scroll on whats app the header of the whatsapp move up and down regarding to the scroll up and down and the project build in angular4, so please give me answer or suggestion based on typescript or simple javascript.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: I am assuming you are aiming for a `sticky div`? Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/

Comment: The question is edited..I tried my best to clear the question.